# Eclipse: Extract Method feature fails

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

For better readability of a lengthy method, I'd like to replace a repeatedly used block of code (only assignments) with a method. I therefore selected the block of code and ran Eclipse's *Extract Method* feature, but that failed with this error:

> Ambiguous return value: Selected block containsmore than one assignment to local variables. Affacted variables are:
>
> ```
> int foo
> double[] bar
> ```

How can I fix this? It should be a simple `void` method doing a couple of assignments, I'm not sure what Eclipse (3.6.2) complains about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse wants all variables that are used as arguments and return one or no variable that was modified within the extracted block.

You issue is a construct like

```
void f2() {
        int a,b;
        int foo=0;                           // selection start
        double[] bar = new double[10];
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < bar.length ; i++ ) {
            bar[i] = foo;
        }
        foo = 0;                             // selection end

        a = foo;
        b = (int) bar[0];
    }
```

Since both variables (foo,bar) are needed in further statements they can't be returned as one value.
You could return a class containing foo and bar.

Declareing them as member variables works

```
public class Refactor {
    int foo ;
    double[] bar; 

    void f2() {
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < bar.length ; i++ ) {        // selection start
            bar[i] = foo;
        }
        foo = 0;                                          // selection end
    }
}
```

as well as this:

```
void f2() {
        int foo=0;                                  // selection start
        double[] bar = new double[10];
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < bar.length ; i++ ) {
            bar[i] = foo;
        }
        foo = 0;                                    // selection end
    }
```

Comment: I see the problem, the assignments wouldn't "stick" as I'd modify them locally - what was I thinking? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Are these only assignments or are they also declarations? Because it looks like they were declarations. And when you try to extract them into a method the variables would be visible only in the new method and thus, Eclipse want's to return them, to make them available in the calling blocks.

If it is possible, you could make the variables global (i.e. member variables) and then put the assignment code into an extra method

EDIT:

As stacker pointed out, Eclipse wants to return all variables that were modified in the new method. Since Java uses call-by-value this is necessary for primitive types. Because assignments to them are only visible in the extracted method, but not outside.